# How to remove flutter on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to remove/uninstall flutter on ubuntu (16.04). I have not found any solution on the Internet.

Thank you very much!

Comment: just delete the flutter folder also delete the plugin

Comment: First we need to know how exactly you installed `Flutter`?

Answer (score 28):

If you have installed flutter from **snap**, then you must execute:

```
sudo snap remove flutter
```

Comment: Worked for me since I installed using `snapd`. I ran `flutter doctor` and it said 'Command not found but may be installed with...`.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted the folder itself.
You can also reset your PATH variable (if you had previously set it to include flutter as well) so that when you run `flutter doctor` in your **terminal**, you will get `command not found` which means it's not there anymore

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu software centre and remove the flutter application from installed applications